# Java static nested classes in separate files

Tags: java, inner-classes

I'm working on my own game engine and came to a wall that stopped me. When I'll be coding a game I will simply use my gameengine.jar as a library. But I want to reference some classes with a god-class "GameEngine".

In this example I will want to use a class "Logger" that simply logs errors. Both GameEngine and Logger don't have a constructor, they are static.

```
public class GameEngine{
  public static Logger logger = Logger; // ERROR
}

class Logger{
  static void logError(){
    System.out.println("Error");
  }
}
```

I want to do `GameEngine.logger.logError();` but can't.
I could use a nested class but both classes are very long.

Comment: I am pretty sure Java does not have a concept of "God class", but you can make 'GameEngine' a package instead with 'Engine' or 'Game' and 'Logger' a classes?
If you import it just right, you can use the syntax you want.

Comment: Why do you need to do GameEngine.logger.logError()? It is a static class you can just do Logger.logError() and it would do the same thing? Or you could add a getter if you really wanted then it becomes GameEngine.getLogger().logError(); ? It seems like you can do what you want, just not the way you want it. Also, they do both have constructors, its just that it uses the default constructor if you haven't told it to use a different one. You will only lose the constructor if you explicitly make the constructor private. Just because a class is static doesn't mean it doesn't have a constructor

Answer (score 0):

**Solution A:**

```
public class Logger{
  public static void logError(){
    System.out.println("Error");
  }
}
```

And from anywhere in the code then:

```
Logger.logError();
```

**SOlution B if you want to call it from GameEngine on top:**

```
public class GameEngine{
  public static Logger logger = new Logger();
}
```

(Meaning the constructor of Logger isn't private)

then from anywhere in the code:

```
GameEngine.logger.logError();
```

Standard logging API

There no reason for you to re-implement a logging API while dozen of them exist in Java.

For example there log4j that is well known: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/api.html

And there also a standard in java to hide the actual logger implementation and provide a common interface (https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Logging/article.html)